# How to load variables defined in dir-locals before mode-hook has been called?

Tags: emacs

I want to define some variables in .dir-locals.el, then I add a hook to python-mode-hook, in the hook, I want to read the variables defined in .dir-locals. The problem is that mode hook is called before loading .dir-locals.el

Any ideas to swap the loading sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot swap the sequence.  It is hardcoded in `normal-mode`.

However, you can hook in at `hack-local-variables-hook`, which runs *after* all local variables were set.  Assume you have the following currently:

```
(defun my-python-hook-function ()
  (message "Hello world"))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my-python-hook-function)
```

You can simply change this to:

```
(defun my-local-variables-hook ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'python-mode) (my-python-hook-function)))

(add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook #'my-local-variables-hook)
```